# Is this business logic in my view model, and is it allowed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WCF service that must be always up, and is therefore hosted by a Windows Service. My Windows Service model has simple startup code:

**HostService:**

```
public void StartService()
{
    if (_hostController.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped && _hostController.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
    {
        var msg = string.Format("Service '{0}' must be in status '{1}' or '{2}' to accept a 'Start' command.",
            HostResources.ServiceName, ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending);
        throw new HostServiceException(msg, HostServiceException.HostServiceExceptionCategory.ServiceStatusControl);
    }
    try
    {
        _hostController.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is Win32Exception || ex is InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new HostServiceException(string.Format("'{0}' failed to respond properly to a 'StartService` command: '{1}'", _hostController.ServiceName, ex.Message), ex);
        }
        throw;
    }
    try
    {
        _hostController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, _waitForStatusTimeout);
    }
    catch (TimeoutException tx)
    {
        throw new HostServiceException(string.Format("{0} did not start respond after {1} seconds and the 'Start' command timed out.", _hostController.ServiceName, _waitForStatusTimeout.TotalSeconds), tx);
    }
    if (ServiceControllerStatus.Running != _hostController.Status)
    {
        throw new HostServiceException(string.Format("The 'StartService' command for '{0}' failed. The Service has a status of '{1}'.", _hostController.ServiceName, _hostController.Status));
    }
}
```

My WCF service has even simpler startup code:

**SchedulerService:**

```
public void Start()
{
    _isBusy = false;
    var interval = _config.Settings.ServicePollingInterval * 1000;
    _pollTimer = new Timer(interval);
    _pollTimer.Enabled = true;
    _pollTimer.Elapsed += PollTimerElapsed;
    _pollTimer.Start();
    Status = SchedulerServiceStatus.Running;
    var msg = string.Format("'{0}' started with the timer set for {1} second{2} intervals.", SchedulerResources.ServiceName, _pollTimer.Interval / 1000, _pollTimer.Interval / 1000 > 1 ? "s" : "");
    _logger.Info(msg);
    StatusChanged(this, new SchedulerStatusChangeEventArgs(Status, msg));
}
```

It is the code in my view model in question here, because only if it can start the Windows Service, will it start the WCF service:

**SchedulerViewModel:**

```
private void ExecuteStart()
{
    if (_hostModel.ServiceStatus != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    {
        _logger.Warn("The '" + _hostModel.ServiceName + "' host service is not running. The '" + GetType().Name + "' will attempt to start it.");
        try
        {
            _hostModel.StartService();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = string.Format("The '{0}' could not start the '{1}' host service: {2}", GetType().Name, _hostModel.ServiceName, ex.Message);
            _logger.Error(msg, ex);
            throw new HostServiceException(msg, HostServiceException.HostServiceExceptionCategory.ServiceController, ex);
        }
    }
    try
    {
        _scheduler.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new SchedulerServiceException(ex.Message, SchedulerServiceException.SchedulerServiceExceptionCategory.SchedulerControl, ex);
    }
    SchedulerStatus = _scheduler.Status;
    CommandsCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Now this is indeed not view logic, but it is hardly business logic either; more like housekeeping: I can only use the washing machine if the water supply is switched on. Now I don't really see the need for a whole new model with just an instance of `HostModel` and `SchedulerService`, just for this decision. What say the jury on my current setup?

Comment: Are you using dependency injection and a service layer to host your model?

Comment: The logic that you should be removing is all of the `catch (Exception ex)` blocks. They are worse than using `goto`.

Comment: `ServiceBase.Start` has `void` return type and is documented to throw two exceptions. I understood that to be a safe route that that particular `Start` method had correctly executed. Likewise with the `Timeout` exception for `WaitForStatus`. My alternatives are to set an error property in `HostService` and return `false` if any exceptions occur, or create a special return type for `StartService` that describes any error starting the service.

Comment: @toadflakz No, it's a tiny one model one view Timer based scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would push all the code behind another service and inject this via an interface into the VM, I'd do this becuase I presume the WCF expose state via events and you want to display this in the UI. If you push this behind another service allows to 'shape' the exposed state into a more UI centric model suited for use in the VM.

If you did this, from the view point of the VM all it would then know about is 'start\stop' methods and an event handler - the implementation is then abstracted away and makes testing the VM very easy via mocking.

To take this further I would consider using Reactive extensions instead of CLR events for communicating state changes in the service.

Comment: Could I ask what the benefit is of Reactive Extenstions over standard CLR events? I have never used them!

Comment: it gives you the ability to create a fluent API style chain of method calls to process a stream of data, which can be easily done sync or async. This is done via the Rx LINQ style methods. For me this makes reading and understanding the code easier.

Comment: Yes, I had though of that. Lose the `HostModel` and put both the `HostService` and `SchedulerService` behind a united model, nicely polished for a single VM.

Comment: correct, for any 'Model' would be exposed via this new service and used by the VM.